# how to use compiled vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote some vba code and want to hide it. I know about the password protect stuff, but I found it very unelegant. Instead, opted for code compilation. These are the steps I'm following

1 - open excel

2 - right click on the sheet tab

3 - view source code

4 - write a sub in vb editor

5 - debug / compile vba project

No errors everything's fine

Now, the question is: how do I use the compiled code? Does excel generate something analog to a .jar?

Comment: If you want to use "complied" code in your project without also including the source in the file, there's no way to do that.  If you're not comfortable using password protection on your VBA project then you'll need to create an add-in using (eg) some .NET language.  Note though that those are just as easily "decompiled"...

Comment: what about `PERSONAL.XLSB`?

Comment: An *.xlsb is a binary file, but when open in Excel you can then SaveAs --> any other format.

Answer (score 0):

From your perspective, the `Compile VBA Code` command essentially just does a syntax check for you. It's no different than what happens when you run your VBA project -- it first does a syntax check, reporting any errors that it may find, and then "compiles" your code into an intermediary byte code that is then executed. So you can't remove your `Module`, `Class`, or `Form` objects and have it use a "compiled" version of your project.

If you want to hide your VBA code from prying eyes, lock your project with a password.